# JAX-RS 2.0.1 response Async depending on custom header

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, freemarker

Working in a legacy backend that is build with freemarker and JAX-RS 2.0.1

Using Freemarker has led us down the path of having a custom output Java object/class for every endpoint.

There aren't resources to launch a new version, therefore we are dependent on the old freemarker based frontend to work while implementing new features in a new frontend that could depend on async backend calls.

To get going quickly and use what we have my question is:
Is it possible in a JAX-RS 2.0.1 to have to different responses from the same endpoint on a HTTP GET request, depending on a custom header and is it possible to have a default response if the header isn't set or dosen't exists.

Hope my question is clear, else ask and i will elaborate

Comment: you could use a http filter to check if the header is set and then modify the request to route to your async method

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to then copy-paste the controllers classes one by one and refactor them to async and call prefix the path with "v2/"?

Comment: sure, easier to maintain.

Comment: But then we will end up still being stuck with legacy code, because there wouldn't be a smooth transition

Comment: move your business logic to a common method and call it from both endpoints